# round() returns redundant amount of decimals

Tags: php, rounding, precision, floating-point-precision

I've written many PHP applications and have just stumbled upon a weird scenario. The round function doesn't seem to be working in a very complex set of code. I've tried many different things before calling round, but this just doesn't work. The function returns 0.56000000000000001 when given `round($val,2)`, with `$val=0.5600`. This should obviously return 0.56.

I've changed my code to use `number_format($val,2,',','')`. This seems to have solved the issue, but now I'm 2nd guessing all my other code.

Should I replace round with number_format everywhere? Has anyone had similar errors with round?

Also to note this seems to be linked with PhpExcel which is used in this instance. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to replace `round` with `number_format`. You could use `round` with the flag to round down.

Choose what is best for the application.

- Are you rounding a `float`? Use `round`
- Are you wanting to format a number and group by thousands? Use `number_format`

```
<?php 
$number = '0.5600'; 
echo round((float)$number, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

https://eval.in/297781

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that not every decimal number can be represented exactly in standard floating point. This is a very common problem, yours is not unique. If you need exact representation, then what you're doing, i.e. converting floating point to string, will suffice.

Some other solutions:

- convert `==` with floating point to `<=` or `>=`
- convert `==` to a tolerance, e.g. `b–ε ≤ a ≤ b+ε`, with `ε` some constant or value relative to `|a|` or `|b|` or both